# Spark, Cassandra Keyspace is not found

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, pyspark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to read data from cassandra keyspace but when trying to access that using pyspark, Keyspace is not visible.

It works when using DataStax spark shell =>

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-60-229:~$ sudo dse -u xxxx -p xxxxx spark --conf spark.driver.cores=4
The log file is at /home/ubuntu/.spark-shell.log
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
New Spark Session
WARN  2017-08-28 07:02:21,286 org.apache.spark.SparkContext: Use an existing SparkContext, some configuration may not take effect.
Extracting Spark Context
Extracting SqlContext
Spark context Web UI available at http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = dse://?, app id = app-2017082807xxx1-0002).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
  ____              __
 / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
_\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
/___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.2.6
  /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> spark.sql("show databases").show()
+----------------+
|   databaseName |
+----------------+
|        default |
|          dsefs |
|      OpsCenter |
|staging_keyspace|
+----------------+
```

But when using following code, Only **`default`** is visible.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
import os

os.environ["DSE_USERNAME"] = 'xxx'
os.environ["DSE_PASSWORD"] = 'xxxx'
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("SparkCassandraApp") \
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost") \
    .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", "9042") \
    .getOrCreate()
sql_context = SQLContext(spark.sparkContext)
sql_context.sql('show databases').show()
spark.stop()

+------------+
| databaseName|
+------------+
| default    |
+------------+
```

Comment: try `spark.sparkContext.getConf().getAll()` and see what changed in the configuration between spark shell and pyspark

Comment: tried that and used same conf, But no luck.